# Accessing a struct in C giving segmentation faults

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

Any reason this line of code in C would give me a segmentation fault? Because it is, state is a struct.

```
dec_to_bin( state.mem[ state.program_counter ], mc_binary );
```

I have tried doing pre-assignments like

```
int program_counter_temp = state.program_counter;
dec_to_bin( state.mem[ program_counter_temp ], mc_binary );
```

but it doesn't work either. I don't even enter main when I have these assignments.

This is the state struct

```
typedef struct stateStruct {
int pc;
int mem[NUMMEMORY];
int reg[NUMREGS];
int numMemory;
} stateType;
```

Comment: Problem is not here, you should provide more context because for now it would be just guessing things.

Comment: This is the line causing the segfault. I have tried removing it then adding it again. The assignment is done in a for loop, that's the only context really missing here.

Comment: Did you use `gdb`? What is the value of `state.program_counter`? What is the array size of `state.mem`? Is `dec_to_bin` a macro? What is `mc_binary`?

Comment: 0 and 65536, I can't use gdb because the program crashes before entering main. dec_to_bin is a function call that takes two ints. mc_binary is an int.

Comment: You can and should use `gdb`. Load your program into `gdb` first, and then start it.

Comment: show the definition of the struct?

Comment: All gdb gives me is this Program exited with code 01.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.3.x86_64
(gdb) back
No stack.

Comment: That is not a segmentation fault. Make the segmentation fault happen in `gdb`, then debug.

Comment: how the l are we supposed to know what crashed if you just give the data structure and no code?  maybe program counter runs over the the mem array.  maybe your computer got hot.  maybe there's a parity error reading from memory because you installed crappy memory on your dev machine.

Comment: if the program crashes before main, one possibility is you tried to put the whole structure that is huge on the stack...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of allocation your state machine as a stack variable, why not `malloc()` it and *then* use?

Like this:

stateType state = malloc(sizeof(stateType));

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, from the snippet of code I can see, your `state.program_counter` is exceeding the size of the array `state.mem`.  Make sure that it's not accidentally negative, or greater-than-or-equal-to `NUMMEMORY`.